# Find all permutations of $S_4$ that commutes with (123)

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

This is what I have. Not sure if this is right. $${4\times3\times2\over3}=8 $$ I think this is too easy to be true

Comment: $8$ is not a permutation, is it?

Comment: 8 is the number of permutations

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118144/prove-disprove-find-a-in-s-4-that-is-not-a-power-of-b-such-that-ab-ba-whi

Comment: @behold: But you are not asked for a number of permutations, you are asked for the permutations.

Comment: "Find all permutations..." doesn't mean just find out how many there are; it means find out which ones they are.

Comment: The identity and the inverse, of course.  Any others? nope.

Comment: You've forgotten $(123)$ itself, lol.

Comment: doh... yes and itself.

Comment: I am not understanding @MichaelHardy. I do not see another way to do it

Comment: @Arthur This is different from the one that is claimed to be a duplicate. My question states exactly what I type

Comment: @behold You want all permutations that commute with $(123)$, while the linked question asks for all permutations that commute with $(123)$ and at the same time is not a power of $(123)$. I know your question is not a verbatim copy, but it's close enough in my book.

Comment: To commute with (123) in $S_4$ how am I suppose to go about it? Like (123) commutes with (13) right? @Arthur

Comment: To commute with (123) in $S_4$ how am I suppose to go about it? Like (123) commutes with (13) right? @DougM

Comment: $(13)(123) = (12)\cdots (123)(13) = (23)$ does not commute.